# Why isn't zlibs z_stream::next_in const?

Tags: c++, qt, zlib

I am currently integrating code from another stack-overflow question, that [uncompresses data from a `QByteArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7351507/1839591) into an application.

Since we enabled all the compiler errors, we have to reinterpret_cast and const_cast the QByteArray::data():

```cpp
z_stream strm;
strm.next_in = reinterpret_cast<Bytef *>(const_cast<char *>(data.data()));
```

Why would this input parameter be non-const? In my opinion, this suggests, that the data is somehow modified, which is definitely not what I want and also not what I believe is actually happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the `z_stream` interface functions aren't `const`, presumably for legacy reasons.

You can build zlib with `const` support however by running `configure` with `--const`.